# QGIS does not change y and x coordinates to decimal degrees

Tags: decimal, coordinates, qgis, epsg

I'm not quite familiar with QGIS, but now I have used too much time trying to find a solution of my probably trivial question.

So I have data for Danish administrative areas. So far I have calculated centroids and added y and x coordinates for them. However, I have not been able to convert them to decimal degrees when exporting as CSV. In the "Save Vector Layer as..." I tried changing the CRS to EPSG:4326 which was what I read would do it. But when I export the CSV, the format is not as such (between -180 and 180 for the y coordinate for example).

I would appreciate some help.

Sincerely,

Emil Blicher

Comment: I think you are in the from site. This site is about programming. For gis question, we have a sister site about gis (named gis stackexchange, see links on top right icon). But before asking, be sure your read the QGIS tutorial. Nake sure you had a CRS in original file, and you are not changing CRS, but just you are exporting data with a different CRS.

Comment: Thanks. I will try there then. I am not quite sure, I follow your suggestion, though.